# C++ & GLM: name followed by :: must be a class or namespace name (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c++, namespaces, visual-studio-2015, quaternions, glm-math

I am certain I've set everything up correctly, but there must be something I'm missing. I've included all my headers as such:

```
#include<glm/glm.hpp>
#include<glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include<glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include<glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp>
```

As far as I can tell, all of those are valid, because on their own, the code compiles.
But when I try to write this code below:

```
glm::mat4 view = glm::gtc::quaternion::mat4_cast(qview);
```

I get an error on 'gtc': "Name followed by :: must be a class or namespace name"

What on earth am I missing? Am I using the wrong namespace? It matches what the documentation says it should be: http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.0/api/a00135.html#ae2d14d52f9fef3da00cf867f9e2e3dfa

Incidentally, if the 'logic' of what I'm trying to do is wrong (assigning the value of a mat4 like this) please ignore it: I'll address that problem when I get to it. For now I'm just trying to diagnose this issue with the namespace.

Comment: The compiler is right, as far as I can tell: there's no `namespace gtc` defined in those headers. `mat4_cast` is defined directly in `namespace glm`. Looks like an error in the docs. Does it work if you qualify it as `glm::mat4_cast`?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, it turns out that I was referencing the wrong version of the documentation. I'm using version 0.9.7, and the documentation I was looking at was 0.9.0. The functions I'm trying to use were moved to the glm namespace between those two versions, and work just fine if I do

```
glm::mat4_cast(qview);
```